# My excel pivot table does not show year/month/quarter filters

Tags: excel

I have a table with a "Quote date" column, of which I make a pivot table. The table has been generated by a VBA-program.

In the pivot table field list I get then a "Quote date" field. If I drag that field to the rows-area, I expect to get filters/selectors for years and months. But I don't get that. I only get "Quote date".

Also the first column of the pivot table shows all dates that appear in my original table.

What am I dong wrong?

Comment: Most likely the dates are not true dates but strings ....

Comment: I converted them from strings with @datevalue(). So they are true dates.